# Rails Validate Date in Future (client_side_validation giving me trouble)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, client-side-validation

I have the following code to validate that my date is in the future:

```
  validate :date_must_be_in_future

  def date_must_be_in_future
    if date_in_question < Date.today
      errors.add(:date_in_question, "This should probably be in the future.")
    end
  end
```

And it appears to be working, but it's not showing up in the client_side_validation.  Any thoughts?

Comment: what do you mean by client_side_validation?

Comment: client_side_validations is a gem - https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations

Comment: did you enable the ActionView::Base.field_error_proc in config/initializers/client_side_validation.rb?

Comment: Yes, client_side_validations is working everywhere else, it's just not working here on my custom validation.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem and here is the same question again:
https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/issues/312

So I guess you have to write your own custom validator class as described here:

https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/wiki/Custom-Validators